# org.hibernate.HibernateException- Could not parse configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

hibernate.cfg.xml(2) The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not
>   parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml

this is my xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <mapping class="com.java.utils.Details"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Post the **entire** XML content please and the **entire** exception stacktrace.

Comment: Mods: read the answer and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check these things:

1. XML declaration is present
2. XML declaration should be on first line and there should not be any space before this.
3. xml is not used anywhere.

Comment: In hibernate.cfg.xml check these two:                                            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

Comment: The above error usual comes where there is sapce before xml declaration: <?xml version="1.0" ?>